# Suddenly spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.1:build-image could not download spring-cloud-bindings

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

In the AWS CodeBuild pipeline I got this error during the build-image task:

```
could not download https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.10.0/spring-cloud-bindings-1.10.0.jar
```

The same build fail on my PC and the artifact spring-cloud-bindings-1.10.0.jar doesn't exists anymore on repo.spring.io.

Answer (score 1):

Today the build-image task is working and the spring-cloud-bindings-1.10.0.jar is available from url https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-bindings/1.10.0/spring-cloud-bindings-1.10.0.jar.

The problem cause was a spring repo temporary unavailability.

This is an evidence this task doesn't use maven repository cache mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers having the same or similar issues, you might want to read the relevant article from `Spring` team [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020).

Basically the sum up of the article is, that you better stop retrieving dependencies from `repo.spring.io` and switch to maven central instead.

Reason is that the instance of `repo.spring.io` was sponsored in the past from `JFrog, Inc` but as the situation has now changed they are basically moving to other instances.